# Django: NoReverseMatch at ' '. ' ' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to retrieve data from form inputs and insert them into the model. But I receive this error:

[Error NoReverseMatch. 'test-management/test/add_test/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZJo9.png)

**The .html file that contain form.**

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'test-management/test/add_test/' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <h2>Add Test</h2>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <p>Name :</p>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Test Name...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <p>Type :</p>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="type" placeholder="Test Type...">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <p>Date :</p>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="Test Date...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-right">
                            <input type="submit" value="Add">
                            <a href="." class="btn btn-primary btn-link btn-wd btn-lg" id="close">Close</a>
                            <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-primary btn-link btn-wd btn-lg" id="add_new">Add & New</a>
                            <a href="." class="btn btn-primary btn-link btn-wd btn-lg" id="add">Add</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

The error might be caused by action of the form, but I don't know how to correct it.

**urls.py**

```
from test_management.views import (test_list, subject_list, topic_list, question_list, import_question, add_test)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test-management/test/add_test/', add_test, name='add_test'),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Test

def add_test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test_name = request.POST.get('name')
        test_type = request.POST.get('type')
        test_date = request.POST.get('date')
        test_obj = Test(test_name = test_name, test_type = test_type, test_date = test_date)
        test_obj.save()
        tests = Test.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'test_list.html', {'tests' : tests})
```

**models.py**

```
class Test(models.Model):
    # candidate_id = models.ForeignKey('Candidate', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # admin_id = models.OneToOneField('Admin', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test_name = models.TextField(max_length=45)
    test_type = models.TextField(max_length=45)
    test_date = models.DateField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.test_name
```

Thank for helping me solving the error!

Comment: `{% url 'add_test' %}`

Comment: What do you think the `name` attribute of a pattern is for ?

Comment: @BearBrown thank you. It does work! But the data doesn't store into the model. do you know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As argument of `url` tag you should use url name, not regular expression:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'add_test' %}">
```

Instead of

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'test-management/test/add_test/' %}">
```

Comment: @neverwalkalonerr But the data doesn't store into the model. do you know why?

Comment: @Sokunthaneth sorry, I don't see problem. Probably you should try to use django form instead of fetch data from request manuall. Check this tutorial for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/